# Simulating a mouse click in R

Tags: r, command-line

Is there a way to simulate a left-click from the mouse using R?

I just want that after some line of code, wherever the mouse is, R will make a left click.

I am using Ubuntu - Unity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xdotool.1.html) installed, you could do:

```
system("xdotool click 1")
```

Comment: Any idea how to perform such task without the necessity of using external libraries/tools?

Answer (score 4):

Another option is exploiting the `rJava` package and the java `Robot` class.

```
require(rJava)
.jinit()
jRobot <- .jnew("java/awt/Robot")
pressButton<-function() {
   jRobot$mousePress(J("java/awt/event/InputEvent")$BUTTON1_MASK)
   jRobot$mouseRelease(J("java/awt/event/InputEvent")$BUTTON1_MASK)
}
pressButton()
```

Comment: I guess...  Java is cross-platform and the above should work also under windows. Didn't check though. Obviously you must have java installed.